# Cross platform development with interfaces for Android, iOs, and synch with Windows 7

Tags: android, ios, windows, html, cross-platform

I am researching how to best create a program that will run on multiple mobile platforms (Android and iOS required) and  on a PC with Windows 7 and possibly Linux. The program will need to edit a file and be able to upload this file either to the PC or via USB to a device.

Do I need to develop two programs-- one for the PC and one for the mobile platforms? Or is there an easy way to have the program available for all platforms? 
* And the mobile app must be able to function when the device is offline. 
* The mobile app must update a shared document between the PC and mobile device.
* performance is not a large issue.

Thanks in advanced!